# mdadm raid6 built, but no mounting or fsck

Tags: software-raid, raid6

I had some problems with my RAID 6 drive on mdadm recently. No LVM in between. Two drives died, and were pulled out while the machine was powered down. Now, I boot up the system, and cannot mount the raid.

mdstat says that the raid is active

```
root@NFS:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid6 sdc[5] sdb[3] sde[1] sdd[0]
      7813531648 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/4] [UU_U_U]
```

But when I try to mount it...

```
root@NFS:~# sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/md127 /media/NAS 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md127,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

fsck is the same

```
root@NFS:~# fsck.ext4 /dev/md127 
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md127

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

So, I listed backup superblocks

```
root@NFS:~$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000589e8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   608382975   304190464   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       608385022   625141759     8378369    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       608385024   625141759     8378368   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdd doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sde doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md127: 8001.1 GB, 8001056407552 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1953382912 cylinders, total 15627063296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 2097152 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6f6d8d7f

Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table
jippen@NFS:~$ sudo mke2fs -n /dev/md127 
mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=128 blocks, Stripe width=512 blocks
244174848 inodes, 1953382912 blocks
97669145 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
59613 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
4096 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632
```

And try a few...

```
root@NFS:~# e2fsck -b 7962624 /dev/md127
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md127

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Is there still hope, or is this total data loss?

EDIT 1/12/2014

Output of fdisk -l

```
root@NFS:~# fdisk -l /dev/md127

Disk /dev/md127: 8001.1 GB, 8001056407552 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1953382912 cylinders, total 15627063296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 2097152 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6f6d8d7f

Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

EDIT adding hexdump

```
root@NFS:~# hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/md127
00000000  45 eb 13 54 f6 24 03 0a  17 ad 30 a9 50 4f bd 48  |E..T.$....0.PO.H|
00000010  8c 7f 20 7f f6 5a 63 0e  be bd 7f 4a c2 db ff 00  |.. ..Zc....J....|
00000020  5d c7 dc 8c f2 3f 11 fd  6a 32 00 27 03 3d 41 a7  |]....?..j2.'.=A.|
00000030  b0 c1 cf bf 3f 98 a6 b0  ce 73 df ff 00 ad 5a a5  |....?....s....Z.|
00000040  a0 92 b5 bd 0a e7 04 91  f5 c7 eb 50 ba 16 07 d0  |...........P....|
00000050  f1 fc 85 4c dc 92 07 4e  29 84 85 00 0e c7 9a b5  |...L...N).......|
00000060  b2 b7 64 53 db ee 29 95  c0 20 72 57 ad 64 5f c5  |..dS..).. rW.d_.|
00000070  87 0d ea 09 35 b7 26 77  67 eb fd 2a 9d cc 21 a3  |....5.&wg..*..!.|
00000080  3f 46 cd 6f 4e 5e f1 cd  3d 62 61 51 4e 71 b5 98  |?F.oN^..=baQNq..|
00000090  7a 1a 6d 76 2d 8e 20 a2  8a 28 00 a2 8a 28 00 a2  |z.mv-. ..(...(..|
000000a0  8a 28 00 a2 8a 28 00 a2  8a 28 02 48 f8 39 a7 cd  |.(...(...(.H.9..|
000000b0  39 70 06 6a 0a 7c 6b b9  87 a6 69 03 2d 5a db 82  |9p.j.|k...i.-Z..|
000000c0  0b 9e c3 8a ba 67 54 8c  67 8c 1c 0f 5a a4 f7 3e  |.....gT.g...Z..>|
000000d0  50 0a 3a 81 8a a8 ee 5c  92 7b d4 38 dd fc c6 4f  |P.:....\.{.8...O|
000000e0  71 74 66 24 0e 9c ff 00  3a ad 4a 14 92 2a ec 36  |qtf$....:.J..*.6|
000000f0  d8 5d d8 eb ff 00 d6 aa  b5 a2 fd 49 5d 08 22 b7  |.].........I].".|
00000100  32 30 07 8a b4 2d 82 67  d4 54 bb 42 64 83 ce 09  |20...-.g.T.Bd...|
00000110  fe 55 5a 4b 9d a7 03 f1  fa e0 d2 bf bd f2 2d f4  |.UZK..........-.|
00000120  3d 0c 60 b7 d7 a7 e9 4a  57 04 f7 a4 c6 40 f6 c7  |=.`....JW....@..|
00000130  f4 a7 85 d8 07 35 e4 4b  49 47 cd 33 d1 19 8c 90  |.....5.KIG.3....|
00000140  69 a5 70 4e 2a 43 fa d3  86 39 07 be 7f ad 5a 7a  |i.pN*C...9....Zz|
00000150  3f eb b1 16 d1 15 66 b5  8a f2 36 46 fb de bf 4a  |?.....f...6F...J|
00000160  e5 af f4 b3 04 8d 8e 47  51 f8 e6 ba d2 9f 78 0f  |.......GQ.....x.|
00000170  4a ce b9 8f e6 04 8f af  d3 9a d2 9b b5 fd 56 84  |J.............V.|
00000180  b8 9c 84 d1 15 04 1f f3  d6 a9 95 c1 c5 76 97 9a  |.............v..|
00000190  72 5d c1 b9 38 65 52 7f  9d 72 13 c6 51 d8 1e a0  |r]..8eR..r..Q...|
000001a0  9f d2 bb e9 ce e9 fa 9c  f5 23 aa 22 03 6d 38 70  |.........#.".m8p|
000001b0  0e 69 a7 b6 69 73 91 f8  7f 8d 6d 6f 79 7a 18 8b  |.i..is....moyz..|
000001c0  d2 99 9e b4 e3 ce 73 4d  3d 6a 7a 07 51 41 e2 9d  |......sM=jz.QA..|
000001d0  91 9e 7d 29 99 e2 94 f4  14 2d 9f a8 85 03 3f cb  |..}).....-....?.|
000001e0  f9 52 13 82 3f 0f e9 4a  0f 14 df f0 a4 f7 19 20  |.R..?..J....... |
000001f0  e8 7e 94 11 c7 e2 0d 31  4e 0d 3f 39 07 9f f3 cd  |.~.....1N.?9....|
00000200
```

EDIT More requests for commands

mdadm --detail

```
root@NFS:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Jan 11 20:56:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 7813531648 (7451.56 GiB 8001.06 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953382912 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Jan 11 22:01:47 2014
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : NFS:127  (local to host NFS)
           UUID : 2cde46cb:aa89730c:bb1f214a:cad5bc0a
         Events : 2

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       48        0      active sync   /dev/sdd
       1       8       64        1      active sync   /dev/sde
       2       0        0        2      removed
       3       8       16        3      active sync   /dev/sdb
       4       0        0        4      removed
       5       8       32        5      active sync   /dev/sdc
```

And mdadm --examine

```
root@NFS:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd{b,c,d,e,f}
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 2cde46cb:aa89730c:bb1f214a:cad5bc0a
           Name : NFS:127  (local to host NFS)
  Creation Time : Sat Jan 11 20:56:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813531648 (7451.56 GiB 8001.06 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906765824 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 565612d2:cad5edc9:0848ba81:e06f76a2

    Update Time : Wed Jan 15 22:11:32 2014
       Checksum : 47b3b275 - correct
         Events : 4

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AA.A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 2cde46cb:aa89730c:bb1f214a:cad5bc0a
           Name : NFS:127  (local to host NFS)
  Creation Time : Sat Jan 11 20:56:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813531648 (7451.56 GiB 8001.06 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906765824 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a96bd195:c410fc2f:f0422486:6418d34c

    Update Time : Wed Jan 15 22:11:32 2014
       Checksum : 2047a62f - correct
         Events : 4

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AA.A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 2cde46cb:aa89730c:bb1f214a:cad5bc0a
           Name : NFS:127  (local to host NFS)
  Creation Time : Sat Jan 11 20:56:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813531648 (7451.56 GiB 8001.06 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906765824 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 27e6f0f2:96c41f41:e75d30cc:462cd9bf

    Update Time : Wed Jan 15 22:11:32 2014
       Checksum : 479d0354 - correct
         Events : 4

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA.A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sde:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 2cde46cb:aa89730c:bb1f214a:cad5bc0a
           Name : NFS:127  (local to host NFS)
  Creation Time : Sat Jan 11 20:56:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813531648 (7451.56 GiB 8001.06 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906765824 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fc780ffd:9daf5c50:9a1e4af7:ff5061c7

    Update Time : Wed Jan 15 22:11:32 2014
       Checksum : 939a669d - correct
         Events : 4

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA.A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Comment: what does "fdisk -l /dev/md127" show ?

Comment: Added output to the post

Comment: How about the output of a `hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/md127`? Nothing like looking at the bits to see how scrambled they look. (I'm feeling like you've got a total loss here, though.)

Comment: And that was an MBR-style partition table originally?

Comment: mdadm raid 6 across unpartitioned disks, and made on a separate linux install that had to be replaced once already. Due to the root drive failing. I _believe_ that I just mkfs.ext4 'd the entire /dev/md127

Comment: That makes sense, then, because that doesn't look anything like an MBR -style partition table... >smile<   If I had read you a little more closely I would have seen that you already said that.

Comment: `file` was unable to identify the data. What is the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md127` and `mdadm --examine /dev/sd{b,c,d,e}`?

Comment: Done. Check the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the hexdump, you showed the first 512 bytes, but for an ext4 filesystem it's a too small value, if you see the ondisk format of ext4 in https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Layout you'll see that the first 1024 bytes are left alone as padding to allow the installation of a boot sector. The first contents start at 1024 with the contents of the (first) superblock.

In my case my ext4 filesystems contains 1024 zeros at the beginning, I don't know why do you have binary data there. My opinion is that it could be there from a previous use of the disk (perhaps some initial benchmark?).

```
$ hexdump -C -n 2048 /dev/md3
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000400  00 00 40 00 ee fe ff 00  bf cc 0c 00 97 f4 51 00  |..@...........Q.|
00000410  df 29 3c 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |.)<.............|
00000420  00 80 00 00 00 80 00 00  00 20 00 00 00 ec cf 52  |......... .....R|
00000430  00 ec cf 52 7c 00 ff ff  53 ef 01 00 01 00 00 00  |...R|...S.......|
00000440  3d d6 3d 50 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |=.=P............|
00000450  00 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00  00 01 00 00 3c 00 00 00  |............<...|
00000460  46 02 00 00 7b 00 00 00  bd a1 2f a8 89 c2 46 16  |F...{...../...F.|
00000470  89 2b 9e 82 20 e4 ea 3d  70 6f 72 74 61 67 65 00  |.+.. ..=portage.|
00000480  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  2f 75 73 72 2f 70 6f 72  |......../usr/por|
00000490  74 61 67 65 2f 64 69 73  74 66 69 6c 65 73 00 00  |tage/distfiles..|
000004a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000004c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 fc 03  |................|
000004d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004e0  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0c 7d 05 95  |.............}..|
000004f0  55 9b 49 0c a4 8d 9f b6  9d 26 2f 2f 01 01 00 00  |U.I......&//....|
00000500  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  3d d6 3d 50 0a f3 02 00  |........=.=P....|
00000510  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ff 7f 00 00  |................|
00000520  00 80 78 00 ff 7f 00 00  01 00 00 00 ff ff 78 00  |..x...........x.|
00000530  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000540  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08  |................|
00000550  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 1c 00 1c 00  |................|
00000560  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000570  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  8a 21 c1 04 00 00 00 00  |.........!......|
00000580  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

If this dump you can see that the first 1024 (0x400) bytes are 0, and that there is a superblock with the signature of an ext filesystem at offset 0x38 of the superblock (0x438 of the full output). The magic value is defined as 0xEF53, but these are the bytes 0x53 0xEF the 16-bit value 0xEF53 in little-endian form. In my superblock you can see the label of the filesystem "portage" and that it was last mounted on "/usr/portage/distfiles" among other things. You should search for things like that in the superblock copies.

It seems that you don't have any valid copy of the superblock, so the filesystem is possibly thrashed, but why? why did the two disks failed? do you have something interesting in dmesg? in smartctl -a /dev/sd_? in the kernel log when the two previous disks failed? did the machine worked correctly before? did you shut it down correctly or it died by itself?

RAID6 should be able to survive the hardware failure of two disks, but depending on what failed you could have missed your data. At last resort you can try testdisk, photorec, sleuthkit, etc to try to recover files, but a backup restore should be a better option.

You should really investigate the reason your RAID6 array did not survive and learn from that, avoid getting in the same situation (whatever it was).

And if you can, please post it here so we can all learn.

Comment: root@NFS:~# hexdump -C -n 2048 /dev/md127 |fgrep ef|fgrep 53
    root@NFS:~#
Thats a very bad sign. :|
As far as what happened - no idea. Shut it down to replace fans, started up, and the raid was degraded. One drive didn't show up, and the other smart checked to "degraded, backup and replace", and mdadm showed the drive as failed. I pulled them both out.

And, no backups of a lot of this data, as I have no secondary place to put a couple of terabytes. No idea why these failed - probably bad drives out of the batch. I'll dig into logs, see if there was something that should have altered me

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the posted hexdump **my** idea is that the order sequence of the drives of the RAID6 has been scrambled somehow.  I would try to investigate the first blocks of each of the other three drives and try to find the ext4 super block on one of these.  Before giving up it might be even possible to guess 
every permutation of the drives and by chance you could get your data back.

Disclaimer: I personally stopped using RAID5 and RAID6 long ago in favor of RAID10 and so my personal knowledge about RAID modes 5 and 6 is a bit rusty.
[Why? read this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/storage/why-raid-6-stops-working-in-2019/805)